# Invalid key hash. The key hash does not match any stored key hashes

Tags: android, facebook, hash

I'm trying to make a second login from my android device to my Facebook application.
I have already calculated the hash key with the following code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26450047/1801688

I succeeded to make the first login (registration) to the FB app.
Then i logged out.
Now when i'm trying to log in again i'm getting the "invalid key hash error", like this:
[image]

If i go to the user Facebook setting and remove the application, then i can log in again and blocked again on the second try.

I also tried the hash calculated over the key: "~/.android/debug.keystore" and it made no difference.

I'll be happy to get some suggestions here. Thanks.

Comment: Have you changed the settings to public in the app dashboard

Comment: and are you trying to login from some other device

Comment: Yes, i tried it on a different device. No change.
When connect via browser, the second login works fine.<br>When i use the FB application i'm getting this error.

Comment: and have you change that thing into public??

Comment: Yes, i have.
It didn't change anything.

Answer (score 4):

Verify if you've done the following

Generate your keyhash using 
`keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`

 `androiddebugkey` is the default alias. The default password is `android` .It should then ask for a password. **Make sure that all the above arguments are correct otherwise it will generate a different hash**

Paste this keyhash in the settings tab of the facebook developer console of your app.

In case even after doing this you get the same message verify that the key shown in the error message is the same as one generated by keytool

Answer (score 0):

Just Replace The Error Key Hash With Your Application Key Hash i.e...in  https://developers.facebook.com/app application...!

Answer (score -1):

Easy, delete Facebook app and run project app again