# Key hash not found: facebook sdk

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, hash, facebook-sdk-4.0

I know this question has been asked before so first let me enumerate all the things that I tried without no success:

1. [I made my app live in facebook settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696738/i-am-new-how-do-i-make-my-app-live-on-fb)
2. I publish my app as release mode.
3. [I registered the hash that did not match in the app settings settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28204917/1874460)
4. [I also registered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27290250/1874460) the [hash provided by this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26450047/1874460), publish the app in release mode and the resulting hash was the same hash that i have registered in the  app settings.
5. I executed the command `keytool -exportcert -alias '***' -keystore '****' | '*****' sha1 -binary | '*****' base64` and pasted it in the hash keys in app settings.

The only way that the app would login is if the administrator of the facebook app login. But if someone else use the app and login, the error occurr.

The only one that I haven;t tried is [deleting the fb app and start over](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20304015/1874460) but i would like to know what is that i'm missing first.

I'm I mad? yes. I have try enough? Take a look that the pic bellow(i guess you'll know that color means)

[image]

App and sdk info:

```
android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias '****'
            keyPassword '****'
            storeFile file('****')
            storePassword '****'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "****"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionName "***"
    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        preDexLibraries = false
        jumboMode = false
        maxProcessCount 4
        javaMaxHeapSize "6g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.0.5-beta'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile '****'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.8.0' -- facebook sdk
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile '****'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After hours trying, finally, with all my satisfaction of finding the solution by myself and thanking God(I deserve this moment, I almost literally hit my head on the wall haha), found the solution.

If you specify the `user_birthday` as permission list to facebook sdk. Make sure you also submit the permission to use it in the app review tab. You are not allow it to use by default.
Facebook require some more info like how do you use that permission, and where and etc., etc.